# I need to show the highest DateTime of a given product, however, when I use the code, it shows the same product twice with two different values

Tags: sql-server

I'm from Brazil (sorry for bad inglish, i'm using google translate)...

I need to show the highest DateTime of a given product, however, when I use the code, it shows the same product twice with two different values.

HERE:

- Make a select to display the last movement of each product, since this movement is nonzero.
- Display records sorted by quantity, from highest to lowest.

I need to show only a DateTime of a given product, however, it is showing duplicate and with different datetime.

Code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT      Produto.CdEmpresa, MovimentoEstoque.NumMovEstoque, MovimentoEstoque.CdProduto, MAX(MovimentoEstoque.DataHora) AS UltimaMovimentaçao, 
MovimentoEstoque.QtdMovimento
FROM Produto
            INNER JOIN MovimentoEstoque ON Produto.CdProduto = MovimentoEstoque.CdProduto
WHERE (MovimentoEstoque.NumMovEstoque <> 0)
GROUP BY produto.cdempresa, movimentoestoque.nummovestoque, movimentoestoque.cdproduto, movimentoestoque.qtdmovimento
ORDER BY MovimentoEstoque.QtdMovimento DESC
```

Comment: Please add sample data and desired output to make your question clear.   And while you are editing your question, you should format your code block with the `{}` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for the most recent row for each product. To do this, you need to identify the latest date per `CdProduto`, then use that as a filter to select the row you are looking for.  This is an example of how that should work:

```
SELECT Produto.CdEmpresa
    , MovimentoEstoque.NumMovEstoque
    , MovimentoEstoque.CdProduto
    , MovimentoEstoque.DataHora AS UltimaMovimentaçao
    , MovimentoEstoque.QtdMovimento
FROM Produto
INNER JOIN MovimentoEstoque ON Produto.CdProduto = MovimentoEstoque.CdProduto
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(MovimentoEstoque.DataHora) as DataHora,
        MovimentoEstoque.CdProduto
    FROM MovimentoEstoque
    GROUP BY MovimentoEstoque.CdProduto
    ) as UltimaDataHora
    ON UltimaDataHora.CdProduto = MovimentoEstoque.CdProduto
    AND UltimaDataHora.DataHora = MovimentoEstoque.DataHora
WHERE (MovimentoEstoque.NumMovEstoque <> 0)
GROUP BY produto.cdempresa
    , movimentoestoque.nummovestoque
    , movimentoestoque.cdproduto
    , movimentoestoque.qtdmovimento
ORDER BY MovimentoEstoque.QtdMovimento DESC
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! The `CdProduto` (product code) still repeats, but I believe it's because the datetime is incomplete, showing only the date. I will try to change to what appears the hours too (instead of DateHora is DtHoraLancamento (Date and Time of Launch)).

Comment: I had not thought about making a Select inside another. Because, I'm new to SQLServer. I looked for videos on how to solve this problem. Is this SELECT made within another to be able to organize better?

Comment: This type of select specifically is used to filter like was done above, to choose the row within a set that has a specific, minimum or maximum value. There are other uses of similar types of queries, but they are usually specific to the data needs you have. Just keep in mind that this is a possibility while you decide how you will handle a query -- along with the other 753 possible ways to handle a query, of course :-)